# how to using group by with condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some question about how to using group by `room_location_id`, but when the column `room_code` is having different value the value is not grouping, so I have some table like this :

```
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+  id   + room_location_id + room_code +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   1   +        1         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   2   +        1         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   3   +        1         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   4   +        2         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   5   +        2         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   6   +        2         +     100   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   7   +        1         +     101   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   8   +        1         +     101   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
+   9   +        1         +     101   +
+-------+------------------+-----------+
```

and for the condition is when `room_location_id` have the same value with another row value and when is `room_code` get the same value too, then the `id` will grouping, but when `room_location_id` doesn't have the same value with another row and for the `room_code` too is not having the same value, then the `id` will make a new row, for the table result is like this :

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
+    id     + room_location_id + room_code +
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
+   1,2,3   +        1         +     100   +
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
+   4,5,6   +        2         +     100   +
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
+   7,8,9   +        1         +     101   +
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS id, room_location_id, room_code
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY room_location_id, room_code
ORDER BY room_code, room_location_id;
```

Comment: thanks for answer sir, after I use `GROUP_CONCAT` I must use double `GROUP BY` to get more condition grouping sir?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  If you want a result other than what your question has stated, what is it?

Comment: nope sir, for your answer is enough, I just ask for the explain for your answer sir